# Import js from script tag in HTML file. Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to access data from script tag in html file, produced by cms.
Is it possible to do this without polluting global namespace? 
I've tried to use es6 modules but I've failed and I couldn't find any info about it.

```html
    <script>
        let list = ['a','b','c'];
        export default list
    </script>
```

```js
    //test.js
    import list from './index.html'
```

Error: 
'http://localhost:8080/index.html net::ERR_ABORTED 404'
or:
'Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.'

Comment: you can use `var` to declare the variable so it will be accessible from another files.

Comment: I'm sure I saw somewhere example how to do that for web-component . but not found  the reference

Answer (score 20):

No, doing that isn't covered by the HTML specification yet¹ (and I suspect it never will be²). (If it were, you'd still need `type="module"` on your first script tag.) There's no *module specifier* that specifies a script element in an HTML page. At the moment, the only module specifiers are URLs for JavaScript files. [Details in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system).

Instead, you probably want something like this:

```
<script type="module">
import { setList } from "./test.js";
setList(['a', 'b', 'c']);
</script>
```

...where `test.js` exports a named export that lets you tell it what list to use.

(Or of course, it could be a default export.)

Inline `script type="module"` tags can `import`, but while they can use `export`, nothing can make use of the exports they create because they have no useful module specifier.

---

¹ It's the HTML spec because the form and semantics of *module specifiers* are left to the host environment by the JavaScript spec (details [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule)). All that the JavaScript spec says about them is that they're string literals.

² It certainly *could* be, for instance using fragment identifiers. But with HTTP/2 multiplexing making discrete resource loading so fast compared with HTTP/1.1 (and esp. vs. HTTP/1.0), the impetus to make everything contained in a single resource is dramatically lower now than it was some years ago.

Answer (score 5):

You can't *export* JS from HTML. You can import it however, using the `type="module"` attribute on the `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="module">
  import list from "./test.js";
  //Use list
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also asked myself the same question and found your topic.
But then a simple solution came to mind.

```js
// buffer.js
    export default let buffer={};
```

```html
// index.html
<script type="module">
    import buffer from './buffer.js';
    buffer.helloWorld='hello world';
</script>
....
<script type="module">
    import buffer from './buffer.js';
    console.log(buffer.helloWorld);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a global variable like so:

- In your HTML file:

```
 <script>var myGlobalVar = "foo";</script>
```

- In your JS file before enqueuing your script:

```
/* global myGlobalVar */

alert(myGlobalVar);
```

Then you can use your variable in the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

I had an... interesting... use case at my company where I had to import functions from a file, but the script tag couldn't be a module.

The script tag creates a new script tag in the dom with `type = module`, which imports an object containing each function. For each of the functions we run window.myFunction = myFunction to allow them to be used from the dom.

HTML:

```
<script>
    ((path = "./importme.js", fileId = "importme") => {
        if (document.getElementById(fileId)) return;
        let tag = document.createElement("script");
        tag.type = "module";
        tag.id = fileId;
        tag.innerHTML =
            'import codeFromFile from "' +
            path +
            '"; Object.keys(codeFromFile).forEach(k => { window[k] = codeFromFile[k] });';
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
    })();
</script>
<button onclick="testFunction()">Click me</button>
```

./importme.js

```
function testFunction() {
    alert("Test Function");
}

export default { testFunction };
```

Alternatively, if you just want to run what's in the imported file you could do this:

HTML:

```
<script>
    ((src = "/importme.js", fileId = "importme") => {
        if (document.getElementById(fileId)) return;
        let tag = document.createElement("script");
        tag.id = fileId;
        tag.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
    })();
</script>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
```

./importme.js (wrap everything in the exported anonymous function)

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('click').onclick = e => {
        alert('Element clicked!');
    };
};
```

This is a bad way to do things, only for a worst-case scenario. This answer is food for thought, please don't do this... My company found a way to get around this in the end.

Comment: How did you managed to get around this? I am in a similar situation. With Create React App, it is difficult to import apart from making a dependency a package or keep a local copy.