# HTML Import ignoring <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html-imports

I'm importing an .html file which contains a  tag into another .html file. Here's an example:

File `foo.html`

```html
...
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="bar.html" />
</head>
...
```

File `bar.html`

```html
...
  <script src="bar.js"></script>
...
```

File `bar.js`

```js
console.log("Hello world");
```

In the Chrome DevTools "Network" tab, I can see both `foo.html` and `bar.html` being fetched, but `bar.js` is not, so there is no console log. I can't really see why `bar.html` is ignoring the script tag when it's being imported.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import js from script tag in HTML file. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375215/import-js-from-script-tag-in-html-file-possible)

Comment: [BTW, `rel="import"` is obsolete as of Chrome 73](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports).

Comment: I know it is obsolete, it's not meant for production. I'm not trying to use es6 modules inside the script tag. I'll edit the question so you can have a better understanding.