# How to correctly export a javascript module in Webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am currently experiencing issues exporting a module in webpack. I have been able to export simple modules which contain functions like the following:

```
let getEle = function(item) {
    return document.getElementById(item);
};

module.exports = {
    getEle: getEle
};
```

And in my main.js I will import it like so:

```
import { getEle } from './helper.js';
```

This works without any issues. However, I was trying to export a custom datePicker that I found (namely FooPicker: https://github.com/yogasaikrishna/foopicker):

```
var FooPicker = (function () {
    // code
    function FooPicker() {
        // code
    }
    return FooPicker;
})();

// my attempt at exporting the entire FooPicker module

module.exports = {
    FooPicker: FooPicker
}
```

And I try to import it like so in my main.js:

```
import FooPicker from './fooPicker.js'
```

My attempt at using the module (this works as expected if I simply call the function in a demo HTML file):

```
let foopicker2 = new FooPicker({
  id: 'datepicker2'
});
```

However this does not work and I seeing the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: FooPicker is not a constructor`

I have limited experience working with Webpack and I have done a fair bit of searching but I am still not able to find something relevant to my issue. What am I doing incorrectly here and what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Any chance you want `return FooPicker` instead of `return FooPicker()`? I'm not even sure why you need this anonymous function there, but check this change.

Comment: Sorry those brackets should not be there. I removed them and I am still seeing the same error. Will edit the OP.

Comment: Are you using `this` conspect inside `FooPicker()` function?

Comment: Yes I do use `this` in the FooPicker function. The code can be found here: https://github.com/yogasaikrishna/foopicker/blob/master/foopicker.js. It was a bit too long to post in the OP.

Comment: I don't really know the solution if you tried other exports. Take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375245/8415007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is with `export`

```js
var FooPicker = (function () {
    // code
    function FooPicker() {
        // code
    }
    return FooPicker;
})();

var fooPicker = new FooPicker()
console.log(fooPicker)
```

Try:

```
module.exports = FooPicker

const FooPicker = require('./fooPicker.js')
var fooPicker = new FooPicker()
```

This will work